# Of Face and Circuit Rank

Tags: graph-theory

The [circuit rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_rank) of a graph $G$ is given by

> $$r = m - n + c,$$
>
> where $m$ is the number of edges in $G$, $n$ is the number of vertices, and $c$ is the number of connected components.

Doesn't [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula) say the same?

$$
\#\text{faces} = \#\text{edges}-\#\text{vertices} +\#\text{components} \;\;\;(+\chi), 
$$
where  $\chi$ is [Euler's characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Planar_graphs) of the surface where the graph lives on.

So the circuit rank is just the number of faces, right?

I just wonder since I can't find any face on the Wiki page...

Comment: For a connected graph, the number of connected components is $1$, whereas the Euler characteristic is number of connected components + 1.

Comment: @user17762 isn't $\chi$ related rather to the [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29) of the surface where the gaph lives on than just its *number of connected components + 1*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$
\#\text{circuit rank} = \#\text{edges} - \#\text{vertices} + \#\text{components} 
$$

and, for a planar graph (or a graph on the surface of a sphere),

$$
\#\text{vertices} - \#\text{edges} + \#\text{faces} = \#\text{components} + 1 \text{.}
$$

This leads to

$$
\#\text{circuit rank} = \#\text{faces} - 1 \text{.}
$$

The number of faces includes the outer region. If you do *not* include it then the circuit rank does equal the number of faces.