# Polynomial division first!

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, symmetric-polynomials

$$
x^{28}+9x^{26}+39x^{24}+95x^{22}+76x^{20}-384x^{18}-1928x^{16}-4868x^{14}-7712x^{12}-6144x^{10}+4864x^{8}+24320x^{6}+39936x^{4}+36864x^{2}+16384
$$

In an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3316008/19341) the polynomial above arose. It should have six factors, each like 
$$
(x^4-4x^2\cos(4\pi c_\color{blue}{\text{r}}) +4)
$$
and one like $$
(x^4-4x^2\cosh(4\pi c_\color{red}{\text{n}})+4).
$$
to match the degree $6\cdot4+4=28$ of the first.

Is it possible to first do the polynomial division and then determine the values of $\cos(4\pi c)$?

Or the other way: Why not just multiplying all the factors to get a set of equation? These are elementary symmetric polynomials in the variables $\cos(h)(4\pi c_{r/n})$ with integer solutions.

> Is this approach known to work for a class of cases? What can we say about the angles $\cos(h)(4\pi c_{r/n})$ because of that elementary symmetric polynomial integer solution contraint?

Comment: The $4$th degree polynomials can further be decomposed into $\prod\big(x\pm\sqrt2\exp(\pm i2\pi c)\big)$, resp. $\prod\big(x\pm\sqrt2\exp(\pm 2\pi c)\big)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be your polynomial. It has a number of symmetries. Dietrich Burde's answer exhibits one. We see another by calculating

$$g(u):=2^{-9}f(\sqrt{2u})=32 u^{14}+144 u^{13}+312 u^{12}+380 u^{11}+152 u^{10}-384 u^9-964 u^8-1217 u^7-964 u^6-384
   u^5+152 u^4+380 u^3+312 u^2+144 u+32.$$

A most obvious feature of this is that it is palindromic. Meaning that $u=\xi$ is a zero of $g(u)$ if and only if $u=1/\xi$ is. A common trick taking advantage of this is to write everything in terms of the new variable $v=u+1/u$. It is simple to verify that
$$
u^{-7}g(u)=P(v),
$$
with
$$
P(v)=32 v^7+144 v^6+88 v^5-484 v^4-960 v^3-608 v^2-84 v+23.
$$
Mathematica thinks that $P(v)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$. Judging from the plot it has five zeros in the interval $(-2,0)$ and two positive zeros approximately $0.1$ and $2.1$. If $u$ is real, then $v=u+1/u$ has absolute value $\ge2$. This would yield four real zeros of $f(x)$ subject to symmetries: $x\mapsto -x$ and $x\mapsto 2/x$.

Comment: Have fun finding the zeros of the degree seven polynomial!

Comment: I did not double check, but factoring $P(v)$ modulo a few small primes strongly suggests that its Galois group is $S_7$. Meaning that the zeros cannot be written in terms of radicals (complex or real). More precisely, the Galois group is not a subgroup of $A_7$ and it is triply transitive. I think that's enough to conclude.

Comment: Mind you, I suspect that the origin of $f(x)$ explains the observed symmetries as well as the fact that all the zeros of $P(v)$ are real.

Comment: Jyrki, thanks a lot. The appearance of $S_7$ is sursprising, to me. The polynomial is a factor of the characteristic polynomial of the [Hashimoto edge adjacency operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ihara_zeta_function#Ihara's_formula). The [22-vertex bicubic planar graph](https://graphonline.ru/tmp/saved/lK/lKsWQWuZeWCgTXyX.png) I've started with, doesn't look like to be connected to this group. I gotta try some more examples...

Comment: @draks... I'm afraid I don't know how the Galois group of the extension generated by the eigenvalues of such a beast would be reflected in the structure of that graph (if at all). That is probably fun, though! Too bad I don't have the time to get into this.

Comment: gp pari
? f = 32 * x^7 + 144 * x^6 + 88 * x^5 - 484 * x^4 - 960 * x^3 - 608 * x^2 - 84 * x + 23 ///
%1 = 32*x^7 + 144*x^6 + 88*x^5 - 484*x^4 - 960*x^3 - 608*x^2 - 84*x + 23
? factor(f)
%2 = 
....irreducible.... ///

? polgalois(f)
%3 = [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]  ///
? 
? polroots(f)
%4 = [-1.967499859887757123187509648,
      -1.894434553876928033358117643,
      -1.157069274627468948925830743,
      -1.145188439085367649304516343,
      -0.5444281630827310208468837040,
       0.1285047506388079815948074734,
       2.080115539921444794028050607] ///

Comment: Since the polynomial is a characteristic one of a matrix $W_1$ (Hashimoto edge operator; see linked question) and $\xi$ and $1/\xi$ are roots, wouldn't this point to $W_1$ being [symplectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix#Diagonalisation_and_decomposition)?

Comment: @draks The $\xi\leftrightarrow1/\xi$ symmetry came only after scaling by $\sqrt2$. The zeros of the original degree 28 polynomial form orbits of the group of four transformations generated by $x\mapsto 2/x$ and $x\mapsto -x$. Those quartets are the zeros of the quartic factors $x^4-4x^2\cos(h)\alpha_i+4$.

Comment: But despite the scaling, this means that $\pm\xi$ and $\pm1/\xi=\pm\xi^\ast$ are roots and there are symplectic matrices with the same characteristic polynomial, right?

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial has two irreducible factors over $\Bbb Q$, namely $f=pq$ with
$$
p=x^{14} + 3x^{13} + 9x^{12} + 21x^{11} + 42x^{10} + 78x^{9} + 124x^{8} + 190x^{7} + 248x^{6} +
312x^{5} + 336x^{4} + 336x^{3} + 288x^{2} + 192x + 128,
$$

and

$$
q=
x^{14} - 3x^{13} + 9x^{12} - 21x^{11}
+ 42x^{10} - 78x^9 + 124x^8 - 190x^7 + 248x^6 - 312x^5 + 336x^4 - 336x^3 + 288x
^2 - 192x + 128.
$$

Note that the sign alternates for $q$. Now it is a bit easier to come to the six factors you want.

Comment: thanks for your contribution...

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_{28}(x)$ is the issue polynomial and
$$R(x) = x^{-14}P_{28}(x).$$

[Then](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E28%2B9x%5E26%2B39x%5E24%2B95x%5E22%2B76x%5E20-384x%5E18-1928x%5E16-4868x%5E14-7712x%5E12-6144x%5E10%2B4864x%5E8%2B24320x%5E6%2B39936x%5E4%2B36864x%5E2%2B16384%29%2Fx%5E14%2C%20where%20x%3De%5E%28it%29%20sqrt2)
$$C(t) = R(e^{it}\sqrt2) = 4(64\cos14t+288\cos12t+624\cos10t$$
$$+760\cos8t+304\cos6t-768\cos4t-1928\cos2t-1217),$$
[and](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%204%28-1928%20cos%282%20t%29%20-%20768%20cos%284%20t%29%20%2B%20304%20cos%286%20t%29%20%2B%20760%20cos%288%20t%29%20%2B%20624%20cos%2810%20t%29%20%2B%20288%20cos%2812%20t%29%20%2B%2064%20cos%2814%20t%29%20-%201217%29%2C%20where%20t%3D1%2F2%20arccos%28y%2F4%29)
$$P_7(y) = C\left(\dfrac12\arccos\dfrac y4\right) = y^7+9y^6+11y^5-121y^4-480y^3-608y^2-168y+92.$$

Another way is using of the [Chebyshev Polynomials of the First Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html), then
$$P_7(y) = 4(64T_7\left(\dfrac y4\right) + 288T_6\left(\dfrac y4\right) + 624T_5\left(\dfrac y4\right) + 760T_4\left(\dfrac y4\right)$$
$$ + 304T_3\left(\dfrac y4\right) - 768T_2\left(\dfrac y4\right) - 1928 \dfrac y4 - 1217),$$
[with the same result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%204%20%28-1217%20-%201928%20y%2F4%20-%20768%20ChebyshevT%282%2Cy%2F4%29%20%2B%20304%20ChebyshevT%283%2Cy%2F4%29%20%2B%20760%20ChebyshevT%284%2C%20y%2F4%29%20%2B%20624%20ChebyshevT%285%2Cy%2F4%29%20%2B%20288%20ChebyshevT%286%2Cy%2F4%29%20%2B%2064%20ChebyshevT%287%2Cy%2F4%29%29) (idea of OP author, see the comments).

Easily to show that $P_7(y)$ has only one root out of the interval $(-4,4)$ (proposition of the OP author, see the comments).

Since 
$$P'_7(t+4) = 7t^6 + 222t^5 + 2815t^4 + 17996t^3 + 59472t^2 + 90240t + 39000$$
and 
$$P_7(4) = -29968 <0,$$
then $P_7(y)$ has a single root on the interval $(4,\infty).$

On the other hand,
$$P'_7(-4-t) = 7 t^6 + 114 t^5 + 655 t^4 + 1684 t^3 + 1968 t^2 + 896 t + 88$$
and 
$$P_7(-4) = 16 >0,$$
so there are not roots in the interval $(-\infty,-4).$

At the same time, [the plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%20%2892%20%2B%20y%20%28-168%20%2B%20y%20%28-608%20%2B%20y%20%28-480%20%2B%20y%20%28-121%20%2B%20y%20%2811%20%2B%20y%20%289%20%2B%20y%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%3D0%2C%20-4%3Cy%3C1) of $P_7(7)$

[image]

shows that there are six different roots in the interval $(-4,1),$ which can be easily separated.

[Approximately, the roots are](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%20y%5E7%20%2B%209%20y%5E6%20%2B%2011%20y%5E5%20-%20121%20y%5E4%20-%20480%20y%5E3%20-%20608%20y%5E2%20-%20168%20y%20%2B%2092)
$$y_k\in\{4.16023,0.25701,-1.08886,-2.29038,-2.31414,-3.78887,-3.93500\}.\tag1$$

Since
$$y=4\cos2t,\quad t = -i\ln\dfrac x{\sqrt2},$$
then
$$y=4\cos\left(-2i\ln\dfrac x{\sqrt2}\right) = 2\left(e^{\large2\ln\frac x{\sqrt2}} + e^{-\large2\ln\frac x{\sqrt2}}\right) = x^2 + \dfrac4{x^2},$$
$$y-y_k = x^2-4\dfrac {y_k}4 + \dfrac4{x^2},$$
$$P_{28}(x) = \prod\limits_{k=0}^6\left(x^4-4\dfrac{y_k}4 x^2+4\right),\tag2$$

wherein 
$$y_0 > 4,\quad |y_{1-6}| <4.$$
Therefore, required decomposition of $P_{28}(x)$ is confirmed.

Comment: +1 thanks, doesn't look like there is anything special about the numerical roots. Funny that these (algebraic?) numbers end up in integers, don't you think?

Comment: Further it is interersting that you substitute a $\cos(nt)$ with $t=\frac12\arccos(y/4)$. Isn't that related to [Chebyshev Polynomials of the First Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition)?
That's funny, because in the history of the problem Chebyshev Polynomials of the Second Kind popped up once...

Comment: @draks...Thank you for the comments. Both your ideas are interesting. I will correct the answer.

Comment: @draks...Updated.

Comment: Thanks a again. I'm not sure, about the rational coefficients part. What I meant was something like this: [Geometry of Elementary Symmetric Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1580165/19341): We have a finite product of factors $(x^4-4x^2\cos(4\pi c_{r/n}) +4)$. $\cos(...)$ might not be rational, but in the expanded polynomial, only integer coefficients show up. Doesn't this put any conditions on the angles $4\pi c_{r/n}$ to make this happen?

Comment: @draks...We know that: 1) any integer root is the divider of 92; 2) other rational roots does not exist; 3) should work Vieta's theorem. We can be sure tthat the coefficiets are not rational.

Comment: by construction the roots are given by $\big(x\pm\sqrt2\exp(\pm i2\pi c)\big)$, by that (most probably) not rational. But I'm mean the values of $c$. But maybe I just ran into something, that is not more than an idea without value...thanks again!