# Number of solutions for system of elementary symmetric functions?

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

> The [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) appear when we expand a linear factorization of a monic polynomial: we have the identity
>   $$
>     \prod _{j=1}^{n}(\lambda -X_{j})=\lambda ^{n}-e_{1}(X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n})\lambda ^{n-1}+e_{2}(X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n})\lambda ^{n-2}+\cdots +(-1)^{n}e_{n}(X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n}). 
> $$

Let $\vec v\in \mathbb Z^n$, where the first element is always $0$, *i.e.* $e_1(...)=0$. How many solutions for $X_k\in\mathbb C$ do we get for the following:
$$\vec v=\pmatrix{e_1\\e_2\\\vdots\\e_n}?$$

Some low dimensional numerical experiments point toward $n!$. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true. The condition on $e_1$ is irrelevant, as is the condition that the entries of $v$ are integers. You're asking how many ways there are to order the roots of some polynomial of degree $n$, and the answer depends on their multiplicities. If the roots each have multiplicity $1$ then the answer is $n!$ but, for example, if there's only one root with multiplicity $n$ then the answer is $1$. In general if the roots have multiplicities $m_i$ then the answer is

$$\frac{n!}{\prod m_i!}.$$

Comment: Is there a standard way to get this solutions? A certain kind of transform?

Comment: @draks: you find all the roots of the polynomial, then permute them. Are you asking how to find all the roots or how to permute them?

Comment: Is there no way for something like an exceptional kind of symmetry. I mean the following: Two different sets of $X_k$ lead to the same $\vec v$, which might have plenty of zeros. The question is motivated by [graph-theoretical one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1574334/19341)...

Comment: @draks: that depends on what you mean by "different." Like I said, if you write down the appropriate polynomial with coefficients given by the entries of $v$, then the $X_i$ must be, in some order, the roots of that polynomial (with multiplicity).